# Rounding timestamps in a window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have some data which looks like the following:

```
 userid   | listno | market     |   owned   |     time_stamp      |
--------+-----------+---------------+-----------+----------------
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-02-21 11:22:59 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-15 01:11:59 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-04 15:07:10 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-07 02:33:36 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-08 21:37:21 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-08 21:50:44 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-10 06:29:41 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-11 12:33:42 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-13 00:32:57 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-14 08:05:20 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-02-18 08:00:27 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-02-18 15:01:43 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-02-19 21:14:26 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-14 10:41:41 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-16 00:55:45 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-16 01:00:25 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-16 01:05:18 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-16 01:11:16 |
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-16 01:21:14 |
```

I want to group by hour intervals and then do some calculations. I know how to write the calculations but arriving at the correct grouping is causing me issues. I want to lead each timestamp by the next value, but to also make the lowest timestamp of that hour round down to the hour and the max value timestamp of that hour to round up to the 59th minute of that hour.
This is the query I use:

```
SELECT userid, listno, market, owned, time_stamp, lead(time_stamp, 1) 
OVER (PARTITION BY userid, listno, market, date_trunc('hour', time_stamp) 
ORDER BY time_stamp asc) AS next_ts FROM tableA ORDER BY listno, 
time_stamp asc;
```

That query yields me this:

```
 userid   | listno | market     |   owned   |     time_stamp      |       next_ts       
--------+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-02-21 11:22:59 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-15 01:11:59 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-04 15:07:10 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-07 02:33:36 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-08 21:37:21 | 2018-03-08 21:50:44
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-08 21:50:44 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-10 06:29:41 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-11 12:33:42 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-13 00:32:57 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-14 08:05:20 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-02-18 08:00:27 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-02-18 15:01:43 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-02-19 21:14:26 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-14 10:41:41 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-16 00:55:45 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-16 01:00:25 | 2018-03-16 01:05:18
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-16 01:05:18 | 2018-03-16 01:11:16
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-16 01:11:16 | 2018-03-16 01:21:14
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-16 01:21:14 | 2018-03-16 01:37:38
```

But what I want is the `next_ts` column to be rounded up or down where needed as such:

```
 userid   | listno | market     |   owned   |     time_stamp      |       next_ts       
--------+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-02-21 11:22:59 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-15 01:11:59 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-04 15:07:10 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-07 02:33:36 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-08 21:37:21 | 2018-03-08 21:59:59
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-08 21:50:44 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-10 06:29:41 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-11 12:33:42 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-13 00:32:57 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-14 08:05:20 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-02-18 08:00:27 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-02-18 15:01:43 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-02-19 21:14:26 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-14 10:41:41 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-16 00:55:45 | 
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-16 01:00:25 | 2018-03-16 01:00:00
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-16 01:05:18 | 2018-03-16 01:11:16
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         0 | 2018-03-16 01:11:16 | 2018-03-16 01:21:14
   A    |  1234  |          1 |         1 | 2018-03-16 01:21:14 | 2018-03-16 01:59:59
```

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: I did not quite understand what you want, but to get that rounding I would extract the hour (datetime of course) plus 1 (and create a new date with it) then just do a minus 1 second so for `2018-03-08 21:37:21` With the hour extracted +1 it would be `2018-03-08 22:00:00` - interval 1 second. if rounding up, similar for down

Comment: it's grouped by the hour, so the leading timestamp the minimum value gets rounded down and the maximum gets rounded up

Comment: You could use `date_trunc('hour', lead(time_stamp, 1)) OVER ...`

Comment: ^^ that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is:

- use `row_number` function to identify the first row and the row before the last one
- use the row numbers respectively in `case` statement to modify the timestamps where needed

To produce exactly the output you've specified:

```
WITH
ordering as (
    SELECT userid, listno, market, owned, time_stamp, lead(time_stamp, 1) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY userid, listno, market, date_trunc('hour', time_stamp)
    ORDER BY time_stamp asc) AS next_ts 
    ,row_number() over OVER (PARTITION BY userid, listno, market, date_trunc('hour', time_stamp)
    ORDER BY time_stamp asc) AS rnum_asc
    ,row_number() over OVER (PARTITION BY userid, listno, market, date_trunc('hour', time_stamp)
    ORDER BY time_stamp desc) AS rnum_desc
    FROM tableA 
)
SELECT
userid, listno, market, owned, time_stamp
,case 
    when rnum_asc=1 then date_trunc('hour',next_ts) 
    when rnum_desc=2 then date_trunc('hour',next_ts)+interval '59 minutes 59 seconds'
    else next_ts
 end as next_ts
FROM ordering
ORDER BY listno, time_stamp asc;
```

however, the part with

`2018-03-16 01:00:25 | 2018-03-16 01:00:00`

`2018-03-16 01:05:18 | 2018-03-16 01:11:16`

in your example seems weird to me because `next_ts` is earlier than `time_stamp`. Seems like you're trying to build intervals from an event stream and what you actually need is to round down the first `time_stamp` not the first `next_ts`, so you have a consecutive series of intervals that start from 00:00 and end on 59:59. To do that you just need to rewrite the statement above slightly (CASE statements for both `time_stamp` and `next_ts` columns). The idea stays the same.

Comment: ended up modifying this a bit to fit my needs but this ended up being the basis I needed, thanks!